# Microsoft Partner API <> access denied

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I want to use the Microsoft Partner API to create a referral.

For the authentication, i used this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-us/partner/develop/api-authentication#application-only-access and more specifically the **REST (app-only authentication)** part (it will be a background app).

I did everything but i have an access denied. The error message is pretty generic, is it a problem with my role in azure active directory ?

[get access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndjnw.jpg)
[use the access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7IIN.jpg)

Comment: Hi Max, if still have any problem about get access token and use access token, please let me know.

Comment: Any update about this problem ?

Comment: If do not have any problem about it, please mark my answer as "accepted". In Stack Overflow, we should [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer as "accepted" if it helps the problem. Then more communities are willing to help you in future, you can also get reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The document shows us the permission of the api is "**Delegated**" type, so we can not use client credential flow to get the access token. We should get the token by [username/password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow (shown like below screenshot).

[image]

You can copy your access token to [this](https://jwt.io/) page, decode the token and check if it contains `"scp": "user_impersonation"`

Comment: Hey @hury i let you check my answer. I will mark your answer as accepted after :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the progress here, too long for a comment.

Thank you for your answer! I'm progressing but still have a 401 :

1. I get an access token from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/token)

response : {
"token_type": "Bearer",
"scope": "user_impersonation",
"expires_in": "3599",
"ext_expires_in": "3599",
"expires_on": "1610540194",
"not_before": "1610536294",
"resource": "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com",
"access_token": "....."
}

2. I get an access token from https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/generatetoken

response :

{
"access_token": "",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3585
}

But i still have a 401 from https://api.partner.microsoft.com/v1.0/engagements/referrals

Comment: Can you please share, how to call generatetoken?
Parameters and headers for this API.

Answer (score 0):

Using python I did this. But not able to generate tokens that can help to get customer data.
Code to get access token

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tanat_id+"/oauth2/token"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "return-client-request-id": "true",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "Host": "login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Content-Length": "194",
    "Expect": "100-continue"
}
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'resource': 'https://api.partner.microsoft.com',
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
access_token = json.loads(res.text)["access_token"]
```

Code to generate a token

```
url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/generatetoken"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(access_token),
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
}
data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={"grant_type":"jwt_token"})
```

But

```
>>> res.text
'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid token: tokenValidationResult == null - True, tokenValidationResult.Principal == null - True, tokenValidationResult.Principal.Identity == null- True, tokenValidationResult.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated - "}'
```

Using access_token if I try to get customer list it returns a 401 error.

```
#Customer List

url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers?size=40"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(access_token),
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res
<Response [401]>
res.text
""
```